# using andar for android method to freeze camera

Tags: android, camera, andar

I will explain the situation. I am trying to work out how to pause the camera when a marker has appeared. What i mean by a marker is shown from this link.

http://code.google.com/p/andar/

When the mark has appeared I want a way to pause the camera so the marker wont disappear even though the camera moves. I need this so when playing a game the camera can be jogged but the marker will still stay in the right place. Here is the code form the marker activity

public class CustomActivity extends AndARActivity {

```
CustomObject2 someObject;
ARToolkit artoolkit;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer();//optional, may be set to null
    super.setNonARRenderer(renderer);//or might be omited
    try {
        //register a object for each marker type
        artoolkit = super.getArtoolkit();
        someObject = new CustomObject2
            ("test", "patt.hiro", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);
        someObject = new CustomObject2
        ("test", "android.patt", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);
        someObject = new CustomObject2
        ("test", "barcode.patt", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);
    } catch (AndARException ex){
        //handle the exception, that means: show the user what happened
        System.out.println("");
    }       
    startPreview();
}

/**
 * Inform the user about exceptions that occurred in background threads.
 * This exception is rather severe and can not be recovered from.
 * TODO Inform the user and shut down the application.
 */
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    Log.e("AndAR EXCEPTION", ex.getMessage());
    finish();
}
```

}

@Override

draw function used to draw the cube

```
public final void draw(GL10 gl) {
        super.draw(gl);

        gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR,mat_flash);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SHININESS, mat_flash_shiny);    
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);  
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);

        //this code draws the cube. 
        gl.glColor4f(0, 1.0f, 0, 1.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 12.5f );


        // experement with the api
        //draw the box
      box.draw(gl);
    }
```

Would I wrap code around the startPreview function. Or do I need to check to see if the object is drawn and then stop the preview in that manner.

I found this command but i am not sure how to implement it for when the marker is being displayed. I know i need some of condition but not sure what it is. 
camera.stopPreview();

Comment: What have you tried? The code you posted is the default we give on the project's page.

Comment: I tried to add the pause function but it keeps crashing. Is that the right approach. I will update my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try adding some code that will stop sending the camera preview buffer for processing. That way it will keep rendering the camera preview but will not process new frames.

Comment: could you evaluate. Would I wrap code around the startPreview function